# How to log-in into webpage (http) that is encrypted by login and password in WKWebView

Tags: swift

I am trying to load a pdf from my school's website. This area is encrypted by a username and a password (I know them.)

If somebody tries to open the page, a pop up comes like in the following picture.
[Picture of login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPKys.jpg)

My code until now is:

```swift
let url = URL(string:"http://www.carl-bechstein-gymnasium.de/sicher/klausurplaene/kp_12-1_2017.pdf")
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
pdfView!.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName:"", baseURL: (url?.deletingLastPathComponent())!)
```

This code returns an error

```
2017-10-26 00:54:33.170289+0200 CBG-App[31717:9325935] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
atyp = http;
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
ptcl = http;
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sdmn = Zugangsgeschuetzt;
srvr = "www.carl-bechstein-gymnasium.de";
sync = syna; } failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
```

If you need more information, just comment. How the side is encrypted is a miracle for too. 
I hope somebody can help me soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication used is Basic Auth. The easiest way to access the PDF is use encode the username and password in the URL like this:
`http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.example.com/index.html`

Important:

1. As this is http the username and password can be sniffed from the network traffic.
2. To work in iOS Apps you most likely need to set ATS (App Transport Security) exceptions

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. But there is still the error in the console except "failed to find PDF header: '%PDF' not found". Can I make this disappear somehow? And 1.: that is not my problem, it is the problem of my school ;P; and 2. I already done that. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please open a new question for this. Please include how you set up `pdfView` - might be due to missing encoding?